# Shopify (Liquid) if product has a tag, echo that tag

Tags: shopify, liquid

I'm trying to find product tags that meet a condition, and then display those tag(s).

This gets me all the tags for a product...

```
{% for tag in product.tags %}
{% if product.tags contains '336699' %}
{{ tag }}
{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

How can I just echo the tags that meet the 'contains' criteria?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're almost there. Use [`for`](https://help.shopify.com/themes/liquid/tags/iteration-tags#for) to iterate the `product.tags` and [`contains`](https://help.shopify.com/themes/liquid/basics/operators#contains) within a [`if`](https://help.shopify.com/themes/liquid/tags/control-flow-tags#if) to match `tag` with your string literal criteria.

```
{% for tag in product.tags %}
    {% if tag contains '336699' %}
        {{ tag }}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer!